# union select takes long time to execute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi i have this five select statement and i use union to combine them.
But my problem is it takes 25 seconds to execute is there a way to make this execute way more faster?

```
Select Case when sum(COUNT)is null then 0 end as count,'Exeed45' as tittle from VW_BREAK_TIME_EXCEEDING45
where date_time >=  trunc(To_date('2020-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) and date_time <= trunc(to_date('2020-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))
union
Select Case when sum(CNT) is null then 0 end as count,'Double' as tittle from VW_BREAK_TIME_DOUBLEBREAK
where date_time >=  trunc(To_date('2020-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) and date_time <= trunc(to_date('2020-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))
union
Select sum(COUNT)as count,'Frequent' as tittle from VW_BREAK_TIME_FREQUENTBREAK
where date_time >=  trunc(To_date('2020-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) and date_time < =trunc(to_date('2020-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))
union
Select Count(REMARKS)as count,'LateProd' as tittle from VW_BREAK_TIME_PROD_TIMEIN
where date_time >=  trunc(To_date('2020-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) and date_time <= trunc(to_date('2020-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))
and REMARKS = 'LATE'
union
Select Count(REMARKS)as count,'EarlyOut' as tittle from VW_BREAK_TIME_PROD_TIMEOUT
where date_time >=  trunc(To_date('2020-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) and date_time <= trunc(to_date('2020-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))
and REMARKS = 'Early Out';
```

Hope i say it clear.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: On a side note: Are you sure you want to exclude the last day of March? Don't you rather want `where date_time >=  date '2020-03-01' and date_time < date '2020-04-01'`?

Comment: opps sorry on that i edited my question.

Comment: `and date_time < date '2020-04-01'` includes the whole 2020-03-31, while `trunc(to_date('2020-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))` only includes its very first second. (And `TRUNC` is completely superfluous here. And you should rather use date literals `DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'` anyway.)

Comment: yeah i tried to use Date '2020-01-01' but i cannot incorporate that on stored procedure thats why i use that

Comment: Hm, you should be able to. Date literals work in PL/SQL as much as they do in SQL. But well, I don't know your stored procedure. You may get this date as a string from someplace. Then you must convert it of course.

Comment: yes the supplied parameters on procedure is in string type thats why

Answer (score 1):

First of all `UNION` is a costly operation, not only glueing two results together, but also looking for any duplicates to remove. You want `UNION ALL` instead, which only does the glueing part, because your queries dont give duplicates (as `tittle` is different).

Then there should be indexes on the `date_time` column plus the summed up column for every table:

```
create index idx1 on vw_break_time_exceeding45 (date_time, "COUNT");
create index idx2 on VW_BREAK_TIME_DOUBLEBREAK (date_time, cnt);
create index idx3 on VW_BREAK_TIME_FREQUENTBREAK (date_time, "COUNT");
create index idx4 on VW_BREAK_TIME_PROD_TIMEIN (date_time, remarks);
create index idx5 on VW_BREAK_TIME_PROD_TIMEOUT (date_time, remarks);
```

I'd also add the following indexes for the case `remarks` is more selective than `date_time`. (You can always check the query's explain plan and drop indexes that are not used.)

```
create index idx6 on VW_BREAK_TIME_PROD_TIMEIN (remarks, date_time);
create index idx7 on VW_BREAK_TIME_PROD_TIMEOUT (remarks, date_time);
```

You shouldn't `Count(REMARKS)`, but `COUNT(*)`, as you only want to count rows; `REMARKS` can never be null because of your `WHERE` clause. But I gues the optimizer sees through this and you don't gain speed, only readability.

Two side notes:

1. A date literal looks like this: `DATE '2020-03-31'`. Use these instead of string manipulation.
2. `"COUNT"` is a reserved SQL word. I wouldn't use it for a column name.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand that create index this it is literaly my first time to see that.On the count(remarks) your where correct on that. actualy it is 9.8 seconds in query excute but on my website calling it as stored procedure it takes like 25 seconds is that on the query or in my c# code because my c# code is pretty straight forward

Comment: An index is like a directory. It has all the data sorted by the columns in it, so the DBMS can find the rows in the table almost immediately, just like you find names in a telephone book quickly, because they are sorted. You can give a table many such indexes, so different searches are made easy.

Comment: A query can take longer in a Website, because the Website will not only fire a query, but will have to connect to the database first and then have all the data transferred from the DBMS to the site. 15 seconds sounds very much for this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

- `UNION` will return *unique* rows; if possible, change it to `UNION ALL`
- truncating e.g. `2020-03-01` is useless; what exactly do you think you'll truncate?
- instead of converting string to date (using `to_date`) and (previous remark) truncating it, use date literal (which is always in `yyyy-mm-dd` format), e.g.

  ```
  where date_time >= date '2020-03-01'
  ```
- indexing `date_time` column might help (as well as `remarks`); see what explain plan says
- did you gather statistics on those tables? If not, do it